# How do I insert data if input types are in two different file in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, insert

Basically I have three dynamic dropdowns and 4 normal fields so 7 in total. I did this by using ajax and javascript.

The first one shows the categories

The second one displays the sub category under the category that I chose on the first dropdown

The third one displays the topics under the sub category that I chose on the second dropdown.

Then there's normal input types like gender, occupation and work status.

This file is called testdropdown.php

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","imetrics");



    ?>


    <form name="form1" action="" method="POST">

        <table>

            <tr>

                <td>Select Category</td>
                <td>

                        <select id="categorydd" name="catdd" onChange="change_category()">

                            <option>--None Selected--</option>

                            <?php
                            $query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT category_id, categoryname FROM category WHERE ParentCategoryID IS NULL");
                            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                                ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $row["category_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["categoryname"]; ?></option>

                                <?php
                            }
                            ?>

                        </select>
                </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td>Select Subcategory</td>

                    <td>

                        <div id="subcategory">

                            <select>

                                <option>-- None Selected--</option>

                            </select>

                        </div>

                    </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td>Select Topic</td>

                <td>

                    <div id="topic">

                        <select>

                            <option>-- None Selected--</option>

                        </select>

                    </div>

                </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td>Gender</td>

                <td><input type="radio" name="age" value="male">Male

                    <input type="radio" name="age" value="female">Female

                    <input type="radio" name="age" value="transgender">Transgender

                </td>


            </tr>

            <tr>

           <td>Age Gap Allowed:</td>
                <td><select name="surveyAgeGroup">
                        <option value="">--None Selected--</option>
                <option value="0 18">Below 18</option>
                <option value="18 25">18-25</option>
                <option value="26 35">26-35</option>
                <option value="36 45">36-45</option>
                <option value="46 50">46-50</option>
                <option value="51 100">Above 50</option>
                </select></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>


                <td>Occupation:</td>

                <td><select name="selectOccupation">
                        <option value="">--None Selected--</option>
                        <option value="1">Grade School</option>
                        <option value="2">K-12</option>
                        <option value="3">College</option>
                        <option value="4">Working Student</option>
                        <option value="5">Employed</option>
                        <option value="6">Unemployed</option>
                    </select></td>


            </tr>


                <tr>

                        <td>Work Status</td>

                        <td><select name="employed">
                                <option value="">--None Selected--</option>
                                <option value="1">Part-time</option>
                                <option value="2">Full-time</option>
                                <option value="3">Casual</option>
                            </select></td>

                </tr>

            <tr>

                    <td><input id="btnSaveSurvey" type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Survey">
                    <input id="btnSaveSurvey" type="submit" name="resetsurvey" value="Reset Survey"></td>

                </tr>

            </tr>

        </table>

    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function change_category()
        {
            var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php?category="+document.getElementById("categorydd").value,false);
            xmlhttp.send(null);
            document.getElementById("subcategory").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;


            if(document.getElementById("categorydd").value=="--None Selected--")
            {
            document.getElementById("topic").innerHTML="<select><option>--None Selected--</option></select>";
            }
        }

        function change_subcategory()
        {
            var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php?subcategory="+document.getElementById("subcategorydd").value,false);
            xmlhttp.send(null);
            document.getElementById("topic").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }

    </script>
```

This is the second php file called  ajax.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","imetrics");

$category= isset($_GET["category"])?$_GET["category"]:"" ; $subcat=isset($_GET["subcategory"])?$_GET["subcategory"]:"";

if($category!=""){

    $query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT category_id, categoryname FROM category WHERE ParentCategoryID =$category ");
echo "<select id='subcategorydd' onChange='change_subcategory()'>";
    echo " <option>--None Selected--</option>";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo "<option value='$row[category_id]' selected>"; echo $row["categoryname"]; echo "</option>";
}
    echo "</select>";
}

if($subcat!=""){

    $query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM topic WHERE SubCat = $subcat ");
    echo "<select>";
    echo " <option>--None Selected--</option>";
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo "<option value='$row[topic_id]' selected>"; echo $row["title"]; echo "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
}

?>
```

How and where will I do my insert query in this case? I have 7 fields.

Comment: You have a form with POST. If you submit your form you will get your input in `testdropdown.php`.

Comment: It does not matter where you generate the list of options you show in a select. What important to know when you submit a form (via standard form submission or ajax request it does not really matter) is which control has what value selected. These data are sent to the server for processing.

Comment: What about the two drop down on ajax.php? I would want them included in my insert query @Huelfe